# App Store -"Per language" versions of an app with many assets

Tags: localization, app-store

We are about to ship an app with localization to many languages.
The point is that the localization is not only for the UI but for many assets of the app (offline videos and images, about 200MB for each language).

The app has 50 levels and we wish to ship the app free with 3 lessons inside, so the users won't need to download assets before they decide to buy the rest of the levels.

Obviously we don't want to ship the app more the 20MB and shipping it with 3 lessons for all the languishes can get to 500MB.
The specific language is an important issue as this is a language learning app so we don't want it to be something that the user will have to deal with, he will need 1 language and that's all.

Can we upload language specific versions for the every languish or it will be considered as spamming the app store?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: ITYM "language", not "languish" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that and plenty of companies do it. Search the App Store for "Gengo Wordpower" for example and you will find lots of apps by one company just with a different vocabulary file.